# Como carregar no site uma imagem do servidor FTP pela URL?

Tags: jsf, imagem, ftp

Tenho uma aplicação JSF na qual as imagens que o usuário faz upload são guardadas em um diretório FTP. O modo mais simples que encontrei de renderizar essas imagens é colocando a URL do FTP, com usuário e senha no SRC da imagem:

```
<img src="ftp://user:senha@111.11.111.11/foto.jpg"/>
```

No entanto, deixar essa URL com user e senha expostos é um risco para segurança, sendo que qualquer pessoa que der um F12 no navegador poderá ver essas informações. Como posso ocultar essas informações para renderizar a imagem a partir do servidor FTP?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente acessando apenas o "111.11.111.11/foto.jpg" já seria o suficiente, caso precise de permissão pra leitura, deixe a pasta em questão com permissão 644 no ftp, que assim, todos os grupos terão acessos seguros ao arquivo